# Problem with lstlisting in beamer... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: beamer, listings, columns

I am trying to to put an `lstlisting` environment in the left column, but I'm getting errors. Are `lstlisting` and the `columns` environment in `beamer` incompatible? Or is it something else?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{comment} % end and begin comment
\usepackage{dtklogos} % for \BibTeX

\usepackage{listings} % display code on slides; don't forget [fragile] option after \begin{frame}
\usepackage{bera} % pause in listing
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.92,0.92,0.92} % defining color for listing
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} % defining color for listing

\usepackage{graphicx} % importing figure

\usepackage{verbatim} % writing code 

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
texcsstyle=*\bf\color{blue},
numbers=left,
breaklines=true,
keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
commentstyle=\color{red},
otherkeywords={$},
frame=leftline,
tabsize=2,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgrey},
escapeinside=||
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[float=*]
\pause
\end{lstlisting}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{5cm}
text
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; `columns` and `lstlisting` are not incompatible. You should use the `fragile` option for the frame, and don't treat the listing as a floating object:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{comment} % end and begin comment
\usepackage{dtklogos} % for \BibTeX

\usepackage{listings} % display code on slides; don't forget [fragile] option after \begin{frame}
\usepackage{bera} % pause in listing
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.92,0.92,0.92} % defining color for listing
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} % defining color for listing

\usepackage{graphicx} % importing figure

\usepackage{verbatim} % writing code 

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
texcsstyle=*\bf\color{blue},
numbers=left,
breaklines=true,
keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
commentstyle=\color{red},
otherkeywords={$},
frame=leftline,
tabsize=2,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgrey},
escapeinside=||
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{lstlisting}
\pause
\end{lstlisting}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{5cm}
text
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

On a side note, I see the following line in your code:

```
\usepackage{bera} % pause in listing
```

this is not correct; the `bera` package has nothing to do with being able to use `\pause` inside `lstlisting`; `bera` is just a font package (used to obtain a nice monospaced font).

Comment: thanks, that was probably the most stupid question I have every asked here! I should probably stop working for the day. THANK YOU!